# allow end-user to move a control

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, end-user

I found a good sample [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781245/how-to-allow-user-to-move-a-control-on-the-form/3781344#3781344), but I have a few problems with it.
 1. It is not placing the control to the correct position where the mouse left off becase the control is a big one.

2. It could be pushed out of the screen.. I want it should stay within the screen boundaries.

This is my code:

```
   Public Sub Form1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyControl.MouseMove
    If Not _capturingMoves Then
        Return
    End If
    X = e.X
    Y = e.Y
End Sub

Public Sub Form1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyControl.MouseUp
    If _capturingMoves Then
        ' Do any final placement
        MyControl.Location = New Point(X, Y)
        _capturingMoves = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote something like this for dragging divs on a webpage...

The general approach was to save the coordinates on mousedown, get the coordinates on mouseup, and shift the object's location by the difference.

Here's some example code:

I made a `DragInfo` class that keeps the initial mouse coords and initial location.  I then store one of these guys in the control's `Tag` on the mousedown event:

```
Public Class DragInfo
    Public Property InitialMouseCoords As Point
    Public Property InitialLocation As Point

    Public Sub New(ByVal MouseCoords As Point, ByVal Location As Point)
        InitialMouseCoords = MouseCoords
        InitialLocation = Location
    End Sub

    Public Function NewLocation(ByVal MouseCoords As Point) As Point
        Dim loc As New Point(InitialLocation.X + (MouseCoords.X - InitialMouseCoords.X), InitialLocation.Y + (MouseCoords.Y - InitialMouseCoords.Y))
        Return loc
    End Function
End Class
```

My test control is just a panel that I put from the toolbox.  It could be anything I guess.  Here are my mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup event handlers for the panel (`Panel1`):

```
Private Sub Panel1_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseDown
    Panel1.Tag = New DragInfo(Form.MousePosition, Panel1.Location)
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_MouseMove(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseMove
    If Panel1.Tag IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim info As DragInfo = CType(Panel1.Tag, DragInfo)
        Dim newLoc As Point = info.NewLocation(Form.MousePosition)
        If Me.ClientRectangle.Contains(New Rectangle(newLoc, Panel1.Size)) Then Panel1.Location = newLoc
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_MouseUp(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseUp
    Panel1.Tag = Nothing
End Sub
```

There you go!  That works.  Note that the mousemove method checks if the control is within the form's clientrectangle.

Or, a more generic way to go:

```
Private Sub MakeDraggable(ByVal Control As Control)
    AddHandler Control.MouseDown, Sub(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) StartDrag(Control)
    AddHandler Control.MouseMove, Sub(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Drag(Control)
    AddHandler Control.MouseUp, Sub(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) StopDrag(Control)
End Sub
Private Sub StartDrag(ByVal Control As Control)
    Control.Tag = New DragInfo(Form.MousePosition, Control.Location)
End Sub
Private Sub Drag(ByVal Control As Control)
    If Control.Tag IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf Control.Tag Is DragInfo Then
        Dim info As DragInfo = CType(Control.Tag, DragInfo)
        Dim newLoc As Point = info.NewLocation(Form.MousePosition)
        If Me.ClientRectangle.Contains(New Rectangle(newLoc, Control.Size)) Then Control.Location = newLoc
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub StopDrag(ByVal Control As Control)
    Control.Tag = Nothing
End Sub
```

Now you can just use `MakeDraggable(Panel1)` or any other control to make it draggable!

Edit:  Both examples now keep the control from being dragged out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks
i would appreciate if you're able to provide me with it this sample.

Comment: I realized that keeping the control in-bounds was your principle question.  I fixed the examples to do that.  I check that the control is within the form's clientrectangle.